# Create and align non-rectangular widgets together with PyQt6

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget, pyqt6

I need to create a widget/layout, which will contain a number of non-rectangular, clickable widgets that are well aligned together so that they create a whole (picture below).

[image: Desired widget/layout with smaller, non-rectangular widgets aligned one next to another]

Each of theses widgets needs to be clickable and have a hover option. I thought of using `QAbstractButton` or `QPushButton` class and overriding it's `paintEvent` to draw it with a particular size and shape, but I don't know if this is a optimal solution. I also have no idea how I could then align these widgets together so that there are no empty spaces between them. I thought of using some absolute position of a parent `Window` and manually adjust child widgets position based on that.

Comment: See:: [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).

Comment: Why have multiple widgets at all?  Just manage multiple areas within a single `QWidget` derived control.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you! this might be actually what I need

Comment: @G.M. I'm not sure I do know what you mean and how to do that, any hint with an example maybe?